# Complex Limit with indeterminate form

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this limit but have no idea how to show it. Obviously, we can plug in i for z but then we get an indeterminate form. Our professor has stated we can't use l'hospital so I was wondering if anyone had any insight. I gave also tried to factor the numerator but that does not work either.
$$
\lim_{z\to i} \frac{iz^3-1}{z-i} 
$$

Comment: Why doesn't factoring the numerator work?  $i$ is a root, so $z-i$ is a factor.

Comment: When I factor the numerator I get (1+iz)(z^2+iz-1)  and its not apparent to me what I can do from here.

Comment: Multiply the first factor by $-i$ and the second factor by $i$

Comment: That was super clever, or atleast much too clever for me to realize.  Thank you!

Comment: Not really.  As I said earlier, since $i$ is a root of the numerator, $z-i$ is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

We have : $$\frac{iz^3-1}{z-i} = i \frac{z^3+i}{z-i}$$

Since $z=i$ is a solution to $z^3+i=0$, all you have to do here is to use long division.

$$\frac{z^3+i}{z-i} = z^2+iz-1$$

$$\therefore \lim_{z \to i}{\frac{iz^3-1}{z-i}} = i \lim_{z \to i}{(z^2+iz-1)} = i (i^2 + i^2 -1)$$

$$\lim_{z \to i}{\frac{iz^3-1}{z-i}} = -3i$$

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The fraction is

$$\frac{(-iz)^3-1}{i(-iz-1)}=\frac{(-iz)^2+(-iz)+1}i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Now the factorise-the-cubic approach has been discussed, I may as well mention a use of L'Hôpital's rule,$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{iz^3-1}{z-i}=\lim_{z\to i}3iz^2=-3i.$$The definition of $\left.\frac{d}{dz}(iz^3-1)\right|_{z=i}$ is an equivalent approach.